# ADFS3 -> IdentityServer3 Relying party logout

Tags: identityserver3

We have identityServer3 linked as a relying party to ADFS3 using WSFed. Login works fine. Trying to implement logout. Have added an endpoint in IDServer as specified here https://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/08/federated-logout-with-the-katana-ws-federation-middleware/ however it does not work in that it does not logout of IDServer, it is called OK as have logged the call.

Have been experimenting by calling the logout on the IDServer directly, e.g. ://idserver/logout. But i have to call it twice to get the logout working. The first time i call it I am redirected to the ADFS logout, i can see using fiddler ADFS has an iframe going back to ://idserver/?wa=wsignoutcleanup so i think it is just a case of getting the right code into the cleanup routine for wsignoutcleanup.

I found if i called the logout twice it worked so i tried doing a redirect to ://idserver/logout in the cleanup function. I can see using fiddler the page is called in an iframe but /endsession?sid=xxx is not then called, maybe because its an iframe in an iframe? I have also tried redirecting to endsession?sid=xxxx. I think this worked but only if i called https://idserver/logout not if i call ://adfs/?wa=signout. I am guessing there is something done in logout before calling endsession?

Once this is working I am hoping that our openID/oauth javascript app will pick up that the user session has changed using the checksession endpoint. It does seem to pick up the change when calling logout twice...

Does anybody have a snippet of code we can use in the wsignoutcleanup routine on IDserver that will clear the session properly?

Thanks

Comment: OK, so doing some more fiddling and comparing how Iframes logout for other sites which work I think its "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN" that's stopping the cookies being updated.

So I think I need to disable the adding of the x-frame-options for the logout, then hopefully the cookies will be blanked and it should work. Any ideas on how to stop the x-frame-options being added to logout response?

Comment: Another step closer.... So I have it now that it logs out when I call //idserver/logout the first time, I have made my wsignoutcleanup clean down idsvr, idsvr.partial, idsvr.external cookies and then redirect to //idserver/endsession. What I haven't managed to do is get the logout working when going to //adfs/wsignout the cookies are set ok now, but idserver still seems to think its logged in.

Comment: Its finally working!! Turns out the idsvr cookie is not idsvr but idsrv doh!.. So idserver/logout was working cos it cleaned the cookies then redirected to adfs/singout which did an iframe to idsvr/wsignoutcleanup which redirects to idsvr/endsession. Now I am setting the same cookies to blank in idsvr/wsignoutcleanup its working both ways.

Answer (score 0):

So thought I would post the code that works, not sure if I need to call signout but it all seems to work, might help someone else.....

```
    private static void AddSignoutEndpoint(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
        {
            var qs = ctx.Request.Query;
            var wa = qs.Get("wa");

            if (wa != null)
            {
                if (wa == "wsignoutcleanup1.0")
                {
                    ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete("idsrv");
                    ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete("idsrv.external");
                    ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete("idsrv.partial");
                    ctx.Authentication.SignOut("Cookies");
                    ctx.Response.Redirect("connect/endsessioncallback?sid=" + ctx.Request.Cookies["idsvr.session"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    await next();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        });
    }
```